# How do I open a specific file in a folder same level as solution?

Tags: c#, directory

I am looking for some help.
I have created an application, and one of the buttons is meant to open a specific file.

I have put the specified .txt document into the folder on my program. It is on the same level as the "solution" file.
Now, how do I go about writing the code to open this specific .txt file?

I started out with:
 StreamReader reader; // class-level 
            reader = new StreamReader("../TextFileHere.txt");

But, I keep getting an error message.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

What does this mean & what am I doing wrong? I can easily move the file, if that would make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

put it inside your **bin/Debug** folder and use `reader = new StreamReader("TextFileHere.txt")` instead of `reader = new StreamReader("../TextFileHere.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

With `reader = new StreamReader("TextFileHere.txt")` you will face problems if you put a shortcut of your application somewhere else like desktop. In order to get your appliaction working no matter where the address is, you have to do this:

```
reader = new StreamReader(Application.StartUpPath + "\\TextFileHere.txt")
```